# Exercise on derivative of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I have doubts about the following exercise

$ f(x)= \begin{cases} 0&\text{}\, x<0 \\ x &\text{}\, 0\leq x\leq 1\\ 2-x&1< x\leq 2 &\text{}\, \\ 0 &x>2 \end{cases} $

with $g(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t) dt$

I need

-Find an expression for g(x).

-Where is f derivable?  Where is g derivable?

I am not sure how to order, can someone please help me?

Comment: please check  you text because you defined two different $f(x)$ in the same interval $x \in[0;1]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After correcting your text I explained in my comment, observe that $f_X(x)$ is a triangular function (it's a triangular density function) while $g(x)$ is a CDF.

Your $f_X(x)$ can be expressed in a more compact form:

$$f_X(x)=[1-|1-x|]\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;2]}(x)$$

and, given that it is a triangle, it is not derivable in $x=0;1;2$

To calculate $g(x)$, easy find it by integration finding

$$g_X(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;1]}(x)+\left( 2x-\frac{x^2}{2}-1 \right)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(1;2]}(x)+\mathbb{1}_{(2;+\infty)}(x)$$

which is derivable everywhere

Comment: You are right, I must correct that part thanks bro

Comment: Edited the post and answered at the same time. Nice! (+1)